# Mysql queries in other languages

Tags: c#, mysql, localization

I am writing a windows form application in c# in visual studios 2015 that builds MySql queries from user input i.e.:

select user_input1 from sometable where user_input2 = 'user_input3';

These MySql query strings are then executed from the c# code. This program is going to be used internationally, so I am in the process of making all the strings localized. If a client is using a MySql database in some other country (Germany for example) then do the MySql queries need to be localized to German or will the original English translation still work? I have done some research about this but haven't been able to find any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is in **English**, in fact it was initially called SEQUEL (Structured English QUEry Language) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

So do not worry about translating the queries, as they do not need to be translated into any language.